# Ember JS 2 Changes to HTML got erased after rerender

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

Ember 2. I have a template where I display my model data. And I have a JS script that makes some changes to HTML (inits some JQuery plugins etc), and I need to run it every time I render the view.

I trigger it in the didRender hook of my view. It works fine on the first load. But when I visit the page second time, I can see that plugins are initializing, but in the next moment all changes disappear and the page is as it was initially  in the template.

I guess that there is something that looks for changes in the model and re-render the page after it was rendered in the second time, but I'm not sure about it. I tried to listen for other hooks, like didUpdate, but they are not triggering.

What could be a reason of such strange behaviour?

A simple example:
Js:

```
App.ResumeView = Ember.Component.extend({
    didRender: function () {
        $('.event h6').text('Hi!');
    },
    didUpdate: function () {
        $('.event h6').text('Hi!');
    }
});
```

Hbs:

```
{{#each model.work as |work|}}
    <div class="event">
        <h4>{{work.position}}</h4>
        <h5>{{work.name}}</h5>
        <h6></h6>
        <span class="location">{{work.location}}</span>
        <p>{{work.description}}</p>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Result: on the first load all H6s say 'hi', then if I go to another page and return to this, it shows 'hi' for a second and then it disappears.

Comment: You should probably share some code if you want folks to answer your question.

Comment: Which code would you like to see? Template, Router?

Comment: All the code relevant to the problem, preferably with all the code that isn't part of the thing you're trying to achieve removed to avoid confusion.

Comment: I just added a code exaple

Comment: I don't see you using the `ResumeView` anywhere in your code.

Comment: I don't know about it, can please you give me some information on how to use it?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing with the jQuery plugins. I get the feeling you want to initialise a series of jQuery plugins on a single view and update them all at once when some data changes. This is not really 'the ember way' of doing things. What exactly is the purpose of the jQuery plugins in this particular manner and why are you going about solving the *actual* problem this way?

Comment: I added a code example without any plugins, it also cause a problem. Please take a look.

Comment: Let me rephrase. I think what you want to do can be accomplished without all the jQuery, but I need to know what your jQuery plugin does first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to bet the problem is because the plugins have initialized already, they aren't initializing again.  Try tearing down your jQuery plugins in the `willDestroyElement` event.

Comment: No, I just tried to append text to a random element instead of initializing plugins, this text got erased exact after (I guess) I get a Json response with the model data for that page